# Git Smart HTTP - User Authentication for certain repositories

Tags: git, authentication, version-control, smart-http

I was wondering how you authenticate between git repos for smart http.

For example, I have all my repositories in `/repos/`, however, I would like to assign "John Doe" to only two of them.  The other I want "Jane Doe" to access; however, I don't want either one of them to be able to access each other's repositories.

**By the way:**
I do have user authentication working in genernal with http auth, it's the separating priv. for certain users is what I'm really after.

Comment: Do you need http, or would (restricted) ssh access suffice ?

Comment: I prefer http and previously went the ssh route.

Comment: Apparently gitolite now supports smart HTTP: http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/http-backend.mkd - I'm not sure if its fine-grained access controls extend to smart HTTP as well, however.

Comment: I'll look into how they do this - and post my findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to the developer of https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite and he pointed me in the direction:

```
in short, you need a "mini gitolite"?

(1) set it up the way my man page says but instead of using
gl-auth-command use your script

(2) your script should do/deal with the following:

 - it should take the authenticated username from $REMOTE_USER
 - it should look at the PATH_INFO, REQUEST_URI, etc., to find out
what repo he wants to access and whether he wants to read or write
(you can see the code in simulate_ssh_connection() in my code for
that)
 - then use whatever logic you want to decide if you should allow or
reject the request

If you allow it you must "exec" the original git-http-backend.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using http as a transport, you can use [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV). The official howto is [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/setup-git-server-over-http.txt), but tutorials abound on the web.

Comment: I'm using smart http so that I don't have to use WebDAV.